# Pyqt - Removable widgets: Link button to a function

Tags: function, button, widget, pyqt, removable

In the following code (see download link), I want to create removable widgets in a layout for vector plotting. In a generic removable widget I would like to include a button that allows the plotting. 
My problem is that I can not link the button created (line 49 in the file) to a plotting function (line 60 in the file). Sorry if the question is trivial but I am quite new to Pyqt. You can download the source file from this link:

[Source file download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i20ifeuohm3h05r/sample.py?dl=0)

Thank you very much

Comment: I've fixed the code formatting, but please clarify your question. There does not appear to be a button called `Plot` anywhere. It seems likely you are using a library beyond just plain PyQt. It would be helpful to explain what it is you are doing, what libraries you are using and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, thank you for your prompt response. I will re-edit  the question with more material.